# Backbone.js and Bootstrap Typeahead - rendering after async fetch

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I took the base of this code from a gist.  It initially worked perfectly when I first `fetch()`ed the collection and then in `render()` called tw-bootstap's `.typeahead()`.

However, I have put in a `keypress` event to try and restrict the size of the data returned by `fetch()`.  The collection data is returned and it is filtered through `prepData()` fine and arrives at `render()`.  The typeahead is not working, however at that stage.  It may be that the backbone event is overriding render at that point?

```
// typeahead on the numbers
var Bootstrap = {};

Bootstrap.Typeahead = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#autocompleteN',
    tagName: 'input',
    attributes: {"data-provide": "typeahead"},
    initialize: function(options){
        if(!this.collection) {
            return null;
        }

        //this.collection.on("reset", this.prepData, this);
    },
    events: {
        "keypress": "setSearch"
    },

    setSearch: _.throttle(function(e) {
        var that=this;
        var d = e.currentTarget.value;

        // strip spaces and remove non-numerics
        d = d.replace(/ /g,'');
        d = d.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

        // if it's longer than 2, call a fetch;
        if(d.length > 2) {
            $.when( app.searchNums.fetch({url: 'api/index.php/search/num/'+d}) ).then(function() { 
                //console.dir("success");
                that.prepData();
            });
        }

    }, 1000),
    prepData: function() {
        //console.dir("prepData called");
        var prepare = _.pluck(this.collection.models, 'attributes');
        this.property = this.options.property || _.keys(prepare[0])[0];

        this.items = this.options.items;
        this.data = _.pluck(prepare, this.property);

        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        that.$el.typeahead({
            source: that.data,
            //source: ['PHP', 'MySQL', 'SQL', 'PostgreSQL', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'HTML5', 'CSS3', 'JSON'],
            items: that.items,
            onselect: function( data ) {  
                // render the results view here
            }
        });

        return this;
    }
});

var bui = new Bootstrap.Typeahead({
    collection: app.searchNums,
    items: 5
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just set `minLength` on the typeahead, it looks like that is what you are trying to do?